# How to prove that the first hitting time is measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stopping-times

I'm reading the definition of first hitting time in a class of martingale:

> Assume
>
> - $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb P\right)$ is a filtered probability space.
> - $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a stochastic process adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.
> - $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ a Borel set.
>
> We define a map $T_B: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ by $$\forall \omega \in \Omega: T_{B}(\omega) =\inf \left\{n \geqslant 0 \mid  X_{n}(\omega) \in B\right\}$$ with the traditional convention that $\inf \varnothing=\infty$. Then $T_{B}$ is a stopping time, called the **first hitting time** of $B$.

My textbook as well as Wikipedia's [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stopping_time) do not prove that $T_B$ is actually measurable. By definition, I must show that $$\forall A \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R) : T_B^{-1} (A) \in \mathcal F$$

But I'm stuck at describing the set $T_B^{-1} (A)$.

How can I proceed to prove that $T_B$ is measurable? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $T_B$ can take only integer values or $\infty$. There is sufficient to look at events $\{T_B = n\}$ for all $n$. 
$$
\{T_B = n\} = \bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1} \{X_i \not\in B\}\cap \{X_n\in B\} \in \mathcal F_n\subset \mathcal F.
$$
There is no need to consider $T_B^{-1} (A)$ since it is equals to 
$$T_B^{-1} (A) = \{T_B\in A\}=\bigcup_{n\in A\cap\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}\{T_B=n\}$$

Comment: To add to this answer, it follows that $\{T_B = \infty\} \in \mathcal{F}$, because we  have $\{T_B = \infty\} = \bigcap_n \{T_B \geq n\}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how our task is reduced from checking $T_B^{-1} (A) \in \mathcal F$ for all Borel set $A$ to just checking for $\{T_B = n\}$?

Comment: If $\{T_B=n\}\in\mathcal F$ for all $n$, the last equality implies $\{T_B\in A\}\in\mathcal F$ too.

Comment: @ε--δ Yes, thank you! I found this fact obvious and did not write it because $\{T_B=\infty\}$ is just a complement to $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{T_B=n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that $T_B$ is measurable function it suffices to show that the events $\{T_B \gt t\}$ are measurable for all $t$.  But
$$
\{T_B \gt t\} = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\lfloor t \rfloor}\{X_n \notin B\},
$$
a finite intersection of measurable events.